# Percentage based column / row span

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

I'm wondering if there is a way to use percentage values for `grid-column` and/or `grid-row`.

For example:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
}

.grid-cell-25 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
  }
}
```

See the `span 25%`. My hope is that `grid-cell-25` will span 25% of the available columns in any given breakpoint.

Is this a terrible idea? In this example, for anything bigger than mobile, I have a 12 column layout. And, in mobile, I have a 24 column layout. I wanted to avoid to have to configure "span" for all break points and, instead, use percentage values.

Comment: you want a grid, with 12 columns, but that grid-cell-25 span you wanted to span 25%, meaning 3 columns in your case/ 6 on mobile?

Comment: Yeah probably I want to flip the order. Since in mobile I want the space to be reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to use percentage values for `grid-column` and/or `grid-row`.

No. There is not. This is not how the `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties work.

The `grid-column` property is the shorthand property for `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`. The "start" longhand goes before the slash, and the "end" long hand goes after the slash, like this:

```
grid-column: 2 / 4
```

The rule above is equivalent to:

```
grid-column-start: 2
grid-column-end: 4
```

These properties use **column lines** to determine a grid item's size and location.

In the example above, the grid area would start on grid column line 2 (i.e., the starting edge of the second column) and end at grid column line 4 (i.e., the ending edge of the third column). So it covers columns two and three.

Something like `grid-column: 1 / span 25%` doesn't work because 25% doesn't represent any number of column lines.

This is why the properties above, and their grid row counterparts, are all components of a grid feature known as [**line-based placement**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement).

Your best bet in this scenario is to add a second rule to your media query:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
}

.grid-cell-25 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
  }
  .grid-cell-25 {
    grid-column-end: span 6;
  }
}
```

Comment: I hear you. it makes sense why not to take percentage values.